# How to check if all specifiedn keys exist in array?

Tags: python

For example I have something like this:

```
{'key1': 'value', 'key2': 'value', 'key3': 'value','key4': 'value','key4': 'value'}
```

And have an array:

```
['key1', 'key3']
```

How to check if all keys from second array exists in first?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) and a [generator expression](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators). This will iterate over your array and check that each key is in the keys of `d`. If at least one of the keys is missing then it'll return False.

```
d = {'key1': 'value', 'key2': 'value', 'key3': 'value','key4': 'value','key4': 'value'}
a = ['key1', 'key3']

all(key in d for key in a) # True

a2 = ['key1', 'key5']

all(key in d for key in a2) # False
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [set.issubset()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set.issubset) method to check

```
a = {'key1': 'value', 'key2': 'value', 'key3': 'value','key4': 'value','key4': 'value'}
b = ['key1', 'key3']

set(b).issubset(a)
#True

c = ['key1', 'key5']
set(c).issubset(a)
#False
```

Edit:  apply `issubset` directly on `a` according to @Maroun Maroun comment

Comment: You don't need to apply `set` on `a.keys()`, you can simply check `issubset(a)`.

Answer (score 1):

Another way (using [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set) and [`issubset`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set.issubset)):

```
set(['key1', 'key3']).issubset(your_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a loop and in operator with dict object:

```
adict = {'key1': 'value', 'key2': 'value', 'key3': 'value','key4': 'value','key4': 'value'}

keys_list = ['key1', 'key3']
for key in keys_list:
  if key in adict:
    print key
```

"in" can check if the key in a dict